# OAEP with SHA1 and MGF1 with BouncyCastle?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I am trying to do `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding` with c# using BouncyCastle on .NET Framework 2.0.

I've came down with this:

```cs
IAsymmetricBlockCipher engine = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha1Digest(), new Sha1Digest(), null);
using (var stream = new StreamReader(publicKey))
{
    var pemReader = new PemReader(stream);
    var pemObj = pemReader.ReadObject();
    var keyPair = (RsaKeyParameters)pemObj;
    engine.Init(true, keyPair);
}
var message = "test";
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
var encrypted = engine.ProcessBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
```

**My question is, is that the equivalent to `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding` using BouncyCastle and c# or what is the correct way?**

I am also in doubt with the parameters here:

```cs
IAsymmetricBlockCipher engine = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha1Digest(), new Sha1Digest(), null);
```

I couldn't find a way to define the 2nd `Sha1Digest` into MGF1 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Peter Dettman's GIT](https://github.com/KimikoMuffin/bc-csharp)

It solves this with a IBufferedCipher in a generic class called CipherUtilities in his [unit test (line 302)](https://github.com/KimikoMuffin/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/test/RSATest.cs) he does this like so (line 302):

```
c = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
c.Init(false, privKey);
outBytes = c.DoFinal(outBytes);
if (!AreEqual(outBytes, input))
{
    Fail("OAEP test failed on decrypt expected " + Hex.ToHexString(input) + " got " + Hex.ToHexString(outBytes));
}
```

note that c is a IBufferedCipher

Comment: That seems to work but is NONE equivalent to ECB, can you possible find the code where it converts those strings to their relevant types so I can be sure of it? It does work to encrypt if I change from NONE to ECB but I am reluctant whether or not its being properly converted. Clearing that up the bounty is totally yours! ;)

Comment: Thank you, not my code though, Have a look at Gost3411Digest, line 159. I'm no expert but could be what you needed